# Handling (or by-passing) domain error in calculation

Tags: python, math, exception, logarithm

I have used some code from [here](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/), to convert from latitude to "meters from south pole".

Two unit tests would be convert latitude -90, to get zero as result, and convert latitude 90, which should return the length of a meridian from south pole to north pole.

Problem is this part of the formula:

```
from math import *

my = log(tan((90 + lat) * pi/360.0)) / (pi/180.0)
```

Because when I enter a lat of -90, I get:

```
ValueError: math domain error
```

I guess this has to do with tan function, since it is undefined at `pi/2`

On the other hand, if we are "measuring distance from the south pole", it seems intuitive to me that it should return zero.

So the question is: how I am supposed to fix this formula in a sane way?

I'm sure this probably is a common problem, but I have never had such problem and am unsure what I should do.

UPDATE: this solved my current problem, but I wonder if there is a more beautiful way:

```
    a = tan((90 + self._lat) * pi/360.0)
    b = 0 if a == 0 else log(a)
    c = b / (pi/180.0)
    my = (c * ORIGIN_SHIFT) /180.0
```

Comment: Calculate the expressions you'd send to `log()` and `tan()` in separate steps, then if they're invalid (0 or pi/2), manually set `my` to a useful value?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I did that, will update the question. I still wonder if this is how it's usually done, or there is a more "pure" way to do that (without ifs, ideally).

Comment: If you don't care about minimal errors you could use `log(tan((90 + math.max(lat,-89.9999)) * pi/360.0))`

Comment: How do you get a logarithm in a completely trigonometric problem? Should the formula not simply be `anglefromsouthpole * earthradius`?

Comment: @LutzL perhaps my simplified explanation turned out to be wrong. This formula is part of a map projection (spherical mercator, or "google" projection), so I guess it's more like "latitude to pixels" then "to meters", since in this projection map scale varies non-linearly with latitude.